# My DIVs are not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make responsive my content DIVs, but they are not responsive.

DIV structure is like this -

[image]

**Update :** This is my HTML and CSS

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="content-tertiary col-sm-4">
            my content
        </section>

        <section class="content-primary col-sm-8">
            <div id="main" class="">
                <h1><i class="icon fa fa-user fa-lg"></i><img src="img/misc/title.png" /></h1>

                <div class="sidebar"></div>
                <div class="content-box"></div>
            </div><!-- End main div -->
        </section>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS

```
#main {
    background: #53001E;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 700px;

    > .sidebar {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            float: left;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 10px;
            min-width: 100px;
    }

    > .content-box {
        background: yellow;
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I am using `bootstrap` and dont need to display on mobile view.

Can anybody tell me what is the wrong with this code?

Thank you.

Comment: Read the documentation of bootstrap, especially the grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @Getz, Yes I have read it and these `DIV`s come under `<section class="content-primary col-sm-8">`

Comment: So post more HTML code, we can't see how you use bootstrap classes in your code here.

Comment: you have set max and min width. Still You are expecting the responsive div. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#main {
           background: #53001E;
           border-radius: 10px;
           height: 700px;
           width: 100%;
       }

sidebar {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            float: left;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 10px;
            width :40%
    }

.content-box {
        background: yellow;
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
        width : 60%

    }
```

Let me know for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do the columns, you problem is that you haven't specified a `width` for each of them. They should share the 100% space available. Also, the 10px `margin` on `.content-box` would add up to the width, so it wouldn't fit anymore.

This would be a clean way to do it: http://jsbin.com/hozetoki/1/edit